# MULE ESB TCP request-response pattern to make it work

Tags: mule, esb

I am trying to use the request-response pattern in Mule ESB TCP. The requirement for me is to actually accept the request from client on a port and respond back to the same client socket after processing.

I am unable to find a straight solution for this. Can any one help me with a proper example?

Comment: Which Mule version are you using?

Comment: Mule Version 3.9

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Any issues with the examples there?

Comment: Yes, I read and tried a sample. I actually tried sending back the response via private 
void dispatchToSocket(Socket socket, MuleEvent event) throws Exception.

But I see no error as well as my client is not receiving the messages. I am trying to send a String data from Server from the same socket

Comment: Can you also share me the example link if you have? I am unable to narrow down the correct one

Comment: There is a single page in the documentation for the Mule 3.9 TCP Transport: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/tcp-transport-reference#example-configurations. If you are starting from scratch I advise to use Mule 4 instead, as Mule 3 is nearing its end of life and no new releases should be expected.

Comment: No Mule 3.X is what client is using and we have to use the same. I will check the link and revert back

Answer (score 0):

I have written a TCPAdapter class and handled it. That would be the better way for who ever tries to find a solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).